# Displaying javascript multidimensional array in different HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this multidimensional array below i'm trying to display the `first and last name` in the `H3 tags`, the age in the `H4 tags` and the `person-desc` in the `P tags` and everything inside the tab. I'm not sure the way i am currently displaying the first and last name is the best way to do it. Is there any better / simple way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"Nice guy currently still studying"};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Hot tempered person in the military"};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Smart guy working as a Doctor"};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Loves travelling works overseas"};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0].children;
console.log(parent);
var personFlag = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i=i+1){
  parent[i].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag]['first-Name'] +' '+ personArr[personFlag]['last-Name'];
  personFlag++
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1">
<h3>Name 1 :</h3>   

<h3>Name 2 :</h3>   

<h3>Name 3 :</h3>   

<h3>Name 4 :</h3>   

 </div>
 </div>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are your `person`, `person2`, `person3`, and `person4` objects structured like that, with an array as the key and a string as the value?

Comment: Its part of the requirements cos the data i'm getting is in this format

Comment: interesting! which API are you using?

Comment: also, in your `for` loop, instead of `i=i+1` you can simply use `i++` which will increment `i` by 1 ***after*** every iteration. use `++i` if you want `i` to increment by 1 ***before*** every iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, and personally speaking, using `innerHTML` to modify the DOM in the way you're doing is somewhat frowned on. Instead, you'd create a virtual div, or [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), and each of the "person" divs to that. Once that's done you can append the parent fragment to the DOM. This prevents additional rerendering and is generally more readable.

With your code, I would replace this part:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0].children;
console.log(parent);
var personFlag = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i=i+1){
  parent[i].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag]['first-Name'] +' '+ personArr[personFlag]['last-Name'];
  personFlag++
}
```

With This:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   // `person` is the ith member of personArr
   var name = document.createElement('h3');
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = `Name ${i}: ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   frag.appendChild(name);
});
// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

A non-es6 version would look like this.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
for(var i = 0; i < personArr.length; i++) {
   var person = personArr[i];
   // Create our h3 element, to house the person's name.
   var name = document.createElement('h3');
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = [
       'Name',
        i,
       ':',
       person['first-Name'],
       person['last-Name']
   ].join(' ');
   frag.appendChild(name);
}

// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

Additionally, you would also have to remove all the children from the HTML in order for this to work properly. i.e. make the line1 element look like this:

```
<div class="line1"> </div>
```

Comment: but what if i want to add the other parts as well like the `person-desc` in a <p> tag

Comment: You can do that too :), so after you append the name as a child, you make a new <p> tag using `document.createElement('p')`, and you append that to the fragment as well.

Comment: There are a couple ways of adding properties, for class's specifically, you'd probably use `classList.add`, so you'd get the h3 element, and call that function, e.g. : `person.classList.add('test');`.